# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 on MySQL, Heroku, and Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I am testing simple code with mysql and node.js but it is saying:
`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`

This is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');


module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME
});
```

I just started doing some code of mysql connections. Can anyone fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way heroku works, your web dyno (virtual machine) cannot have a MySQL instance built into it. That is, you won't be able to connect to MySQL on localhost when you use a web dyno.

Heroku offer their own postgreSQL service you can use (you'll have to change your web app code from MySQL to postgreSQL, of course).  Or there are a few different third-party MySQL addon offerings you can install in your Heroku app.  https://elements.heroku.com/addons/

Each of these offerings will require you to connect to it using an environment variable you get from your web dyno.  So if you do something like this, not debugged, you'll be able to run both locally and on your dyno.

```
const dburl = process.env.MYSQL_ADDON 
    ||   'mysql://' + process.env.DB_USER+ ':' + process.env.DB_PASS 
        + '@localhost/' + process.env.DB_NAME

const conn = mysql.createConnection(dburl);
```

The add-on you use has documentation explaining the name and details of their environment variable.

The available third party add-ons have free tiers allowing you to handle a very small (5MiB) database. For databases bigger than that they charge.

Comment: I see it needs a debit card, does it needs payment?

Comment: I don't know anything about the add-on vendors' commercial practices, sorry.